# Is the wedding in "Sword of Destiny" the same event as the one Ciri describes to Galahad in "The Lady of The Lake"?

Tags: the-witcher

Is the wedding in *Sword of Destiny* the same event as the one Ciri describes to Galahad in *The Lady of The Lake*? If so, why does she describe it to him? He was at the wedding as well.

***Sword of Destiny***

The Galahad in *Sword of Destiny* appears only in the end, during Geralt and Yennefer´s wedding. He helped Ciri to kill a monster (probably Cinerea).
He fell in love with her and accompanied her at the wedding celebration. However he seemed to be from different world as he was speaking about Avalon and the Fisher King, which both appear in *The Lady of the Lake*.

***The Lady of the Lake***

Here, Galahad finds Ciri bathing in a lake and starts to call her The Lady of the Lake. She tells him about Geralt and Yennefer´s wedding and about the guests including Milva, Cöen... which are that time already dead.
At the end Galahad asks Ciri to go with him to Camelot and meet King Arthur.

Comment: Still I'm a bit confused by the question and maybe the body *could* use some elaboration. First of all, which wedding are you actually talking about in *Sword of Destiny*? My memory might be a bit hazy, but can you specificy which specific story you're referring to at least? But also, what do you mean "he was at the wedding as well"? Are you talking about Sir Galahad? since he doesn't appear until the very end of the story (in another world altogether), I can't imagine he's made an appearance in *Sword of Destiny* or rather that this would be the same Galahad Ciri meats in Arthurian Britain.

Comment: It wasn't in Sword of Destiny, but additional, non-canon short story!

Comment: But that does not explain the two versions of the wedding

Comment: Sapkowski did write a story about the wedding at one point, I haven't read it and it isn't in the books, but it should be canon. (Possibly only available in Polish?)

Comment: So my take is it's the same Galahad from Lady of the Lake, Ciri takes him with her from that world and the wedding supposedly happens after the events of the books, that end with Ciri taking Geralt and Yennefer to Avalon, which exists in Galahad's world. She meets him early on in the last _book_ but late in the _timeline_, when the main story is already over.

Comment: (To make things even more confusing, Ciri can actually time travel.)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that Ciri and Galahad's conversation at the end of Lady of the Lake takes place before the wedding in Sword of Destiny. That Ciri was telling him her vision of a happy ending for Geralt and Yennefer, as she wished it would be—that's why she included dead people (and burst into tears after saying what she knew was impossible). However, the actual event of the wedding, the epilogue, had to happen later.